# Eclipse does not recognize Message Bundle (f:loadBundle error)

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, weblogic

I'm making a project with maven/spring, but i'm facing a annoying error, eclipse does not recognize my message bundle, if i try to start weblogic inside eclipse (with oracle weblogic server tools), i got this error message and the deploy is aborted:

```
 Multiple annotations found at this line:
 -config.message not found.
 -Resource bundle config.message cannot be found on classpath
```

but if i run the maven build, and start weblogic outside eclipse (startWebLogic.cmd) **it works well**.

in template.xhtml:
`<f:loadBundle basename="config.message" var="msg"/>`

faces-config.xml:

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>pt_BR</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>config.message</base-name>
        <var>msg</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

anyone already had this problem and solved?

Comment: If the message bundle is placed under `src/main/resources/`. Does it exists in Java source folder of the project?

Comment: the properties was placed this way: http://i.imgur.com/42wRuik.png

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution and it's a little shameful ...
I removed the `<f: loadBundle basename =" config.message "var =" msg "/>` in xhtml template because it wad ALREADY declared in `faces-config.xml`, and the 'config.message' do not physically exists the properties file is concatenated with language code, that caused the error on eclipse.